# docker-compose bitnami kafka container I have no name

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose, bitnami

I'm trying to get a kafka instance going inside a docker container. The docker-compose.yml looks like this:

```
version: '2'

services:
  zookeeper:
    image: 'bitnami/zookeeper:3'
    ports:
      - '2181:2181'
    volumes:
      - 'zookeeper_data:/bitnami'
    environment:
      - ALLOW_ANONYMOUS_LOGIN=yes
  kafka:
    image: 'bitnami/kafka:2'
    ports:
      - '9092:9092'
    volumes:
      - 'kafka_data:/bitnami'
    environment:
      - KAFKA_CFG_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181
      - ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER=yes
      - KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092
      - KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS=A_TOPIC,ANOTHER_TOPIC
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper

volumes:
  zookeeper_data:
    driver: local
  kafka_data:
    driver: local
```

The container gives no evident errors when I run `docker-compose up`. However, when I connect to the container's shell

```
docker exec -it [container] /bin/bash
```

I see

```
I have no name!@7fe183af5e2a:/$
```

where 7fe183af5e2a is the container.

Any reason for `I have no name!`? Am I missing something simple?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the [Dockerfile](https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-kafka/blob/master/2/debian-9/Dockerfile) for the Kafka image (the Zookeeper one is similar), you'll see that the user used in the container is the one with the uid **1001**.

So when you see `I have no name!@...`, this simply means that there is no user mapped to the uid 1001. You can verify that if you look into the file `/etc/passwd` you won't see any entry for a user with the id 1001.